# Laptop screens registering as max-width: 320px and orientation: portrait

Tags: css, windows-8, media-queries, landscape-portrait

Tested on an HD Windows 8 IE having laptop and a retina MacBook. No one has had this problem? Seems like putting `max-width: 320px` in there at the end should prevent it since obviously those screens are WAY more than 320px.

```
@media screen, handheld,  
(min-moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
(-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/2),
(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
(min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
(orientation: portrait),
(max-width: 320px)
```

The site is [here](http://luliwines.com/test-site).

Comment: what you want to achieve? why your using smartphone media queries testing on laptop? it can be done via simple css...

Answer (score 0):

Use [(min/max-)resolution](http://www.w3.org/blog/CSS/2012/06/14/unprefix-webkit-device-pixel-ratio/) as the equivalent of `(min/max-])device-pixel-ratio` to support IE:

```
@media (min-resolution: 1.5dppx), (min-resolution: 144dpi), (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/2) {}
```

or through matchMedia:

```
if (window.matchMedia) 
  {
  if (window.matchMedia('(resolution: 96dpi)').matches) { }
  // resolution feature & dppx unit
  if (window.matchMedia('(min-resolution: 1dppx)').matches) { }
  // -webkit-device-pixel-ratio feature
  if (window.matchMedia('(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1)').matches) { }
  // -o-device-pixel-ratio feature
  if (window.matchMedia('(-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1/1)').matches) { }
  }
```

**References**

- [MSDN: resolution media feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh453730.aspx)
- [CSS WG Blog: How to unprefix -webkit-device-pixel-ratio](http://www.w3.org/blog/CSS/2012/06/14/unprefix-webkit-device-pixel-ratio/)